# Load data in form and update row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I load in table form data from mysql. So far so good. Now I have made button called `Update` which open new page where I can update single row in database. The problem is that when I open the update form all the fields are empty and if I want to update just some row and leave blank other fields they are updated as blank in database also which is normal. How can I populate the info into update form?
This is what I use currently to update some record in database.

File `edit.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $id = null;
        if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) 
        {
            $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        }
        if ( null==$id ) 
        {
           echo "null==$id";
        }
        // keep track post values
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $image = $_POST['image'];
            $image_big = $_POST['image_big'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];

                   // update data
           $pdo = Database::connect();
           $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           $sql = "UPDATE food set name = ?, image = ?, image_big = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?";
                    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $q->execute(array($name, $image, $image_big, $description, $id));
                    Database::disconnect();
                    echo "<code>Updated!</code>";

          // html form
```

If I leave for example `name` empty and put some new data in all other fields when I hit `Update` button in database `name` will be blank.

Updated with part of the `html` form

```
<!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="meal_name">Име</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
```

Other fields are the same..

Comment: Can you show your `html` form?

Comment: how you are calling the update page , please provide the respective code.

Comment: It is the same file `action="" method="post"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case please try to put something like this on the `<input>` field where you check if field is empty and asign.(**Didn't tested it)**

```
value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>"
```

So your form fields will become like

```
<!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I'll test this and will let you know if it works.

Comment: So when i load the page all data is populated in the form except of images. Why they didn't load?

Comment: I will accept your answer since is working. For the image I will figured it out.